# Is it worth adding images to tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Since anime and manga is a visual medium, would it be a big benefit to add a small image to anime and manga tags (as in, the [cowboy-bebop](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cowboy-bebop) tag wiki would have a small image of the series). It would be similar to the small image you see on the wikipedia pages for these anime and manga, small image for Fair Use purposes to help describe the the tag.

I can see where this would help because a promotional picture can sometimes help someone identify which anime they are asking a question about, if they're not sure of the name; though in retrospect, that's probably not likely to happen.

There may need to be some sort of guidelines so the images aren't huge or spoilery.

Comment: Do you mean small icons next to the tag names? Or images inside the tag wiki itself?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I was referring to the tag wiki itself, didn't know about small icons next to the tag names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Helpful images in tag wikis are welcome.

Much like you said, they add a lot in a very visual medium such as anime and manga. Adding images can be a great addition to a tag wiki, for the exact reasons you've listed.

I say go for it! ~♪

Comment: We went for it ~♪

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the following guidelines for images in tag wikis:

- Only one image per wiki. The point of the image is to show what the series looks like visually, and that can be accomplished in one image. More images are just clutter. In the case with multiple series with significantly different art styles encompassed by one tag (perhaps [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto) is an example of this?) then an exception can be made.
- The image should show (at least some of) the main character(s) of the series. I think this is self-explanatory.
- No fanart. It'd be strange to judge a series based on its fanart, so why would you report on it on that basis? If you can't tell if the art is official or fanart, chances are it's close enough to the real thing that it isn't worth worrying about.

Stylistic recommendations:

- Images should be as canonically chosen as possible. Images of characters wearing strange clothes, or extremely warped images which would give an incorrect idea of what the art style is, are a bad choice. Images that are very commonly used in promoting a series and are likely to be used on other sites as well make a good choice.
- More distinctive/memorable images are better. If a series has a distinct style, find an image that highlights that, not hides it.
- Ideally, the title should also appear somewhere in the image. This might not always be possible. Some series do not ever show the title in the same image as the characters. If you can't find anything meeting this then it's not worth fretting over.
- The best images fill the available area well, but not to the point where you can't see the whole thing in one screen. On my monitor, that means at least 568 pixels wide, and no more than 724 pixels long. Use your best judgement with this, but a very long and thin image probably isn't the best choice (neither is an extremely wide one).