# What kind of details should be in tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Recently I edit some wiki tag, usually I give a picture, English title, Japanese title, other title, production detail, plot, and some link to wikipedia, wikia.

I'm not sure if I should also add detail like list episode, chapter, character, link to MAL or others, and genre or references.

There's also a [guideline for images in tag wikis](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/431/2869) by @LoganM that say there should be only one picture, but sometimes I think I should add picture from both anime and manga or light novel (if exist) since it sometimes kinda different.

so to summarize my question, what is the best way to fill wiki tag?

Comment: As a practical consideration: basically nobody reads tag wikis (as opposed to excerpts), so it honestly doesn't really matter too much. This is sort of a structural defect in the way the whole tag wiki system is designed. It's useful for some large tags on Stack Overflow (e.g. the programming languages) but for our site, tag wikis serve no real purpose that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

- A nice big *illustration* showing the main characters;
- *Work type* − anime series / movie / short / OVA / ONA / manga / novel / light novel / one-shot, etc;
- *Work names* − official English and Japanese titles, alternative titles, short titles;
- *Creators' names* − mangaka, director, artist, animation studio, etc;
- *Genres* − preferrably combined from several sources like Wikipedia, MAL and such;
- *Plot summary* − short description of what it's all about, preferably original;
- *(Special notes)* − maybe this work has some unique new features in terms of genre or references;
- *List of related works* − sequels, prequels, spin-offs, specials, remakes, summaries, etc with release dates and official dubs;
- *(Viewing recommendations)* − sometimes it's better to watch the whole thing in order different from release dates.

Comment: Are we gonna do this for every tag or just the few that are used a lot (excluding the tag for identification requests and resources)?

Comment: Logan said tag wikis aren't a priority right now, and I must agree with him. Right now tag excerpts serve the purpose of confirming that this is the work the op is looking for, and tag wiki is there to dispel all remaining doubts. What I've proposed goes beyond that already, and aside from identification, it provides additional info about the work, so you decide if you want to spend the time on it.